# Odd Results From pip freeze - Includes Python Packages With Non-Existing Version Numbers and Ubuntu Packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Got a *requirements.txt*-file that is supposedly the result of a *pip freeze*. The file contains several references with wrong version numbers, for example:

```
Collecting python-apt==1.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 183))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-apt==1.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 183)) (from versions: 0.0.0, 0.7.8)
No matching distribution found for python-apt==1.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 183))
```

Another example:

```
Collecting pygobject==3.26.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 170))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygobject==3.26.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 170)) (from versions: 3.27.0, 3.27.1, 3.27.2, 3.27.3, 3.27.4, 3.27.5, 3.28.0, 3.28.1, 3.28.2, 3.28.3, 3.29.1.dev0, 3.29.2.dev0, 3.29.3.dev0, 3.30.0)
No matching distribution found for pygobject==3.26.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 170))
```

In addition, there are references to Ubuntu packages, for example:

```
Collecting pdfshuffler==0.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 144))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pdfshuffler==0.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 144)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pdfshuffler==0.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 144))
```

Got two questions:

1) How can one get such a result from *pip freeze*?

2) What is the best way to proceed to fix it? Fixing the *requirements.txt* by hand? Or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `requirements.txt` that is **supposedly** the result of `pip freeze`

Well, if you don't know the origin and source of the file how could we know?

> 1) How can one get such a result from pip freeze?

Probably someone edited it by hands.

> 2) What is the best way to proceed to fix it? Fixing the requirements.txt by hand? Or something else?

Yes, fix it manually.

Comment: Never seen anything similar in a requirements.txt, so the question should perhaps have been; "Have anyone seen something like this before?", and if so, "How can something like this happen?". Just worried about how this mess came into being...